# Where can I buy the sefer Imros Tehoros?

Tags: product-recommendation

I discovered a wonderful sefer on the Otzar HaChachma program (and on Hebrew Books here http://www.hebrewbooks.org/15241) and can't find a copy of it in any bookstore. It's called אמרות טהרות and is on Bava Metziah. The last printing of the book seems to have been in the 60's.

Where can I get this book? I live in Israel, so if anyone knows of a place here to look that would be the best.

[I do not want to order a copy made from the PDF on HebrewBooks since, as the comment shows on the HebrewBooks page, that version is missing many pages.]

Comment: if you live in boro park you can go to pinters on 45th st and 14th avenue as he sells tons of used in various conditions there and this book can be possibly found on his dollar tables outside. or you can go to any place similar to his that sells old out of print stuff. in flatbush there is mizrahi book store and he has an ebay pagehttp://stores.ebay.com/Jewish-Bookshop . i think pinters wants to start an ebay page but he is too slow on that

https://www.yelp.com/biz/pinters-hebrew-book-store-brooklyn if i remember correctly you can call him and he can ship a book to you if you pay for it

Comment: This link is to another E-Book version not on HebrewBooks.org. The version on HebrewBooks has 231 pages. The version on this link has 295 pages. It looks like you can download the whole book for free. If you wanted to have it softbound at a quick printer, it would be easy.   https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hwmfhh;view=1up;seq=296

Comment: @YaacovDeane That website does not even let me see the book. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting. I copied the link from the download page. I wonder if it requires going to the root of the page. Either way, the Lehmann's link I gave as an answer is easier. They definitely have a couple of volumes and they are new. I purchased Seforim from them before. They were great.

Comment: @Gavriel There is a tab in the bottom left of the screen which opens up a navigation bar and download button. But you might want to just use Lehmann's.

Comment: I'd think it's Amaros, not Imros.

Answer (score 1):

You can order a new hardbound copy from Lehmanns.

http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/amrvt-thrvt-bba-mciea.html

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a copy of the Sefer from Amazon in Hebrew with this link

[https://www.amazon.com/Sefer-Imros-Tehoros-Yehudah-Hebrew/dp/B008JKYYOG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008JKYYOG)

Comment: welcome to mi yodeya Josh! thanks for the answer!

Comment: If that is using the Hebrewbooks PDF, it's missing many pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can currently order a used copy on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hebrew-IMROT-TEHOROT-on-Bava-Metzia-/371758963652?_trksid=p2385738.m2548.l4275). If I were you I would jump on it quick before someone else comes along!

(No, I am not the owner of this eBay account so this is not a sales pitch.)

Another option would to click the "[Order Print Version](http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/t/22776)" button on the HebrewBooks link and order a reprint of the sefer.

**Edit:** The copy that was being sold on eBay was purchased by the OP. The sefer can still be obtained by the second link.